# EF 4.1 CodeFirst GetValidationErrors

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, dbcontext

If I have defined next in map file (1-to-Many relationship between Units and Machines):

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Unit)
    .WithMany(t => t.Machines)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UnitId);
```

When I add new entity, Machine.UnitOfMeasurement = null, sp why does DbContext return no validation problem when calling GetValidationErrors and what can I do to detect them. If I allow EF to try to update, it will return meaningless message to user, like foreign key reference error, while I can extract meaningful information to user from DbEntityValidationResult (ex property name that issued a validation error).

I am using IDataErrorInfo for validation rules, not Attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF validation does not validate navigation properties. The reason for this is that a navigation property may be null not because a related entity does not exist but because lazy loading is enabled and the related entity is just not loaded. Also, even if the navigation property is null you might have set the corresponding foreign key property which basically means that relation exists but the navigation property has not been updated yet. Also note that forcing loading related entities would mean that validation brings your entire database to memory (after loading related entities they will be validated what would result in loading related entities of newly loaded entities and so on) - you don't want this to happen (EF actually turns off lazy loading during validation to prevent from this). 
EF Validation does not support IDataErrorInfo - only validation attributes and IValidatableObject.

Comment: Isn't it normal expectation for EF to check if there is a value in reference property, IF in Map we set HasRequired? At this point we dont care if a value that is entered is correct, we just care to notify user that NULL is not acceptable. You are speaking here about situation where have Reference and ReferenceId on entity, and we set ReferenceId, then Reference could be null, if this object is not loaded in memory. I agree with that, but if we set ForeignKey("ReferenceId") on Reference property, isn't it normal to expect that EF check see if ReferenceId is set, if Reference contains null?

Comment: 1) No. If a navigation property is null it may mean either that there is no related entity (which is an invalid case if HasRequired is set) or that the related entity has not been loaded yet. To make sure that the related property is really set or not would have to have another trip to the database. This is costly and may result in loading half of the database to memory - a situation you always won't to avoid.

Comment: 2) No. Setting a foreign key to a value does not have to be correct. What if there is no entity with the value you set the foreign key to? In addition validation in EF validates values based only on the attributes and facets. It does not have any specific logic to do cross checks against 2 or more properties.
Having said that (1 and 2) - validation in EF is extensible - you could use the CustomValidationAttribute, a custom attribute (an attribute derived from ValidationAttribute class) or IValidatableObject to extend the built-in validation with your own custom rules and it will just work.

Comment: Hi, Pawel, it seems that you didnt understand what I am trying to say. Case: Map has HasRequired set on Reference property. My point is that EF can to a basic check for NULL value on Reference (==null) AND Zero value ReferenceId (== 0), to know that Reference has invalid value, without going into the database, and throwing exception for FK violation. I am not saying that EF should know if I set correct value, I am saying that EF should now that NULL is incorrect value in any case.

Comment: I don't understand why ReferenceId == 0 is an invalid value - for me it is as good as any other key value. Keys don't have to be autogenerated and even if they are they don't have to start at 1. 
Therefore the logic you are proposing will not work for every model. To avoid bogus validation errors (and additional trips to the database) EF does not validate navigation properties. Similarly, EF does not cross-check multiple properties. If a validation rule like you proposed works for you can implement it and EF will use it.